# How do you delete ^\ SIGQUIT characters from the terminal in C

Tags: c, bash, libreadline

So I'm trying to reproduce bash, and when I press control + \ in bash it does nothing. So I'm trying to reproduce that behavior this is my code.

```
# include <signal.h>
# include <readline/readline.h>
# include <readline/history.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <unistd.h>

void    sig_handler(int sig)
{
    write(2, "\b \b", 2);
}

int main(void)
{
    signal(SIGQUIT, sig_handler);
    while (1)
    {
        char *line = readline("test> ");
        if (!line)
            break;
        free(line);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

When I press control + \ , it works the first time but then when I press it again it starts showing the ^ character, so how am I supposed to do this? I'm on macOS btw.

to compile this code run `gcc main.c -lreadline`

Comment: `stty -echoctl` achieves the effect. You need to read the documentation for [`tcgetattr()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcgetattr.html), `tcsetattr()` and the [`<termios.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/termios.h.html)
header to achieve the same effect. There may also be a method in the GNU readline library to do the job; I'm not familiar enough with it to know for sure. The `<termios.h>` link lists `ECHOCTL` as 'reserved for XSI-compliant systems', meaning that it isn't directly supported by POSIX, but was standardized elsewhere.

Comment: Note, too, that macOS doesn't use the GNU readline library — it uses an emulation of it.